# Proper way to convert number to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, tostring

According to tutorial by w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring_number), we can use `toString()` method on a integer var. Kindly look at the following code:

```
var num = 15;
var n = num.toString();
alert(isNaN(n));
```

If `toString()` method is working, why `isNaN(n)` returning `false`?

Comment: You tried with: `var num = 15; var n = num + ""`?

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) is *not* the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Comment: @Oka, sorry for the confusion

Comment: **[Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)** and isNaN function

Answer (score 3):

The `IsNaN` method tries converting the string passed to it back to a number, and since "15" is still actually a number, the method returns `false`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 1):

[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) coerces the string `'15'` into a number value before checking it.

`isNaN` even coerces booleans, and some falsy values into numbers.

```
isNaN(true) // >> false
isNaN(false) // >> false
isNaN([]) // >> false
isNaN('') // >> false
```

Try using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to figure out if it's a number or not

```
var num = 15;
var n = num.toString();
alert(typeof n === 'number');
```

Answer (score -1):

isNaN() function returns true if the value is NaN, and false if not.
Your code is excute alert(isNaN(15));

So it is return false